# Why can't I find Javafx desktop application in Netbeans 10 after coding it

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I downloaded Netbeans 8.1  http://netbeans.org/downloads and then downloaded scene builder and installed them successfully on Windows 10

But after coding my first app
I used clean and build button in netbeans but i when i run the app jar file nothing running but when i opened the task manager in Win10 i found the app shows java. ! i wanna someone tell me how to get it.Thank you

when i used build  button in netbeans  the output was :

```
> ant -f "C:\\Users\\Omar Ahmed\\Documents\\Any" jfx-rebuild 1init:
> deps-clean: Created dir: C:\Users\Omar Ahmed\Documents\Any\build
> Updating property file: C:\Users\Omar
> Ahmed\Documents\Any\build\built-clean.properties Deleting directory
> C:\Users\Omar Ahmed\Documents\Any\build clean: init: deps-jar: Created
> dir: C:\Users\Omar Ahmed\Documents\Any\build Updating property file:
> C:\Users\Omar Ahmed\Documents\Any\build\built-jar.properties Created
> dir: C:\Users\Omar Ahmed\Documents\Any\build\classes Created dir:
> C:\Users\Omar Ahmed\Documents\Any\build\empty Created dir:
> C:\Users\Omar
> Ahmed\Documents\Any\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output Compiling
> 1 source file to C:\Users\Omar Ahmed\Documents\Any\build\classes
> compile: Created dir: C:\Users\Omar Ahmed\Documents\Any\dist Detected
> JavaFX Ant API version 1.3 Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar Warning: From JDK7u25
> the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR
> repurposing.
>          Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'. Launching <fx:deploy> task from
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar No base
> JDK. Package will use system JRE. No base JDK. Package will use system
> JRE. jfx-deployment-script: jfx-deployment: jar: jfx-rebuild:
 **BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)**
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you convert the Project File into a .jar File?

1. Right-click on the ***Project*** name.
2. Select ***Properties***.
3. Click *Packaging*.
4. Check ***Build JAR after*** Compiling.
5. Check Compress JAR File.
6. Click OK to accept changes.
7. **Right-click** on a **Project name**.
8. Select **Build or Clean** and **Build**.

In the Project Folder You will find your PC app as a jar file in the FOLDER named ***dist***.

Comment: I tried that but the problem is the same and when i double click on the javafx app "Civil SQL.jar" using *Java(TM) Platform SE binary*   it didnt open !

Comment: @OmarAhmed try this way in this  [youtube_link](https://youtu.be/4BI5TFyrTP0)
if this don't work share your project if possible

Comment: when i tried to open like what was in video it said unable to reach this file

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK .jar executions invoke Java which envelopes your application => task manager shows java.

If you package it as an EXE, it will show the name, icon and whatever else as it'll run as a self-contained applicaiton which invokes the VM through java.

Comment: ALL_Right it worked with me and ALL wait u said is 100% TRUE thanks alot sir,

Comment: glad i answered your question